# timespec redefinition error occurs after applying all known solutions

Tags: multithreading, compiler-errors, pthreads, timespec

so I'm using visual studio 2019 and I installed pthread package but whenever I run my code the following error pops up "**'timespec': 'struct' type redefinition** "

the most common solution I found is to put `#define HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC` before including pthread.h but whenever I do so two errors occur:

1-  **LNK2019   unresolved external symbol __imp__pthread_create referenced in function _main**

2- **1 unroslved externals**

I know this problem is common but I didn't find any solution to the two new errors specified.

Comment: We cannot reliably debug the issue from the information provided, so the best way forward, whether to discovering the problem for yourself or to getting a diagnosis from us, is to trim it down to a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: What we can tell you is that you are getting definitions of `struct timespec` from two different sources -- probably, but not necessarily, from two different headers.  If one of those is `pthread.h` and the other is from MSVC[++], then the pthreads implementation you have installed is not fully compatible with your implementation, but it's also possible that one of the definitions is in your own code.

Comment: The link error is an altogether separate issue.  The pthreads package you installed ought to provide at least a few words of documentation for how to include the pthreads library in the MSVC++ link. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/2402272.